# Do only 40 countries have rule of law?

Tags: law

In the November 26 issue of *Mishpacha Magazine*, there was an interview with Joseph Wippl (a former CIA agent, now a [Professor at Boston University](http://www.bu.edu/experts/profiles/joseph-wippl/)) in which he said that only 40 countries have real rule of law, and the rest don’t have an independent judiciary.

The magazine [pull quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote) read,

> There are only about 40 countries in the world that function under the rule of law. The remainder do not even have an independent judiciary.
>   — Prof. Joseph Wippl

Here is a photo of the quote:

[image: Wippl quote]

(Unfortunately I don’t have an internet source. It was in a print interview with him which I can’t find online.)

I am not asking about the veracity of the quote (I accept that Wippl actually said it). I want to know whether what he said is accurate.

Comment: And in which group was he placing the USA?

Comment: I expect the rule-of-law country group, from context.

Comment: Where was the print interview published? Could you copy a full quote from the article?

Comment: @Christian I've added a picture.

Comment: @ike: Could you still add the source in which the quote was published?

Comment: @Christian http://www.mishpacha.com/ It's the latest issue dated November 26 (page 36). I don't doubt that he actually said that, just whether the claim is true.

Comment: @ike: Just because you don't doesn't mean that other people believe that magazine to quote accurately. There no good reason for strong trust. The fact that you misrepresented the claim and ommitted the "about" illustrates how easily people put false claims into the mouths of other people.

Comment: @Christian Anyway, have I added enough info, or is more needed?

Comment: @Benjol: there is a difference between rule-of-law and rule-of-lawyers

Comment: "Pull quotes need not be a verbatim copy of the text being quoted; depending on a publication's house style, pull quotes may be abbreviated for space and/or paraphrased for clarity, with or without indication." [Wikipedia: Pull Quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote)

Answer (score 12):

### Rule of law

Looking for independent evidence (i.e. other than the claim referenced in the OP), there are the "[Worldwide Governance Indicators](http://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/index.aspx)" from the World Bank, which include a measure of "rule of law".

The [Rule of Law](http://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/rl.pdf) PDF is an overview of how they measure "rule of law". It includes not only "independent judiciary" but many dozens of other measures including:

- Extent of crime
- Speed of justice
- Compensation for state expropriation
- Intellectual property rights
- The public's trust in the system
- Tax evasion
- Whether there's a "parallel economy"
- Whether court orders are enforced
- etc. etc. etc.

It seems to be a sliding scale (not a boolean measure) from more to less rule of law. You can't easily say, "these have it and these don't".

The [dataset/spreadsheet shows](http://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/index.aspx?fileName=wgidataset.xlsx):

- The usual suspects i.e. the Scandinavian countries are at the top of the list
- The usual suspect i.e. Somalia at the bottom of the list

If I sort all countries in the spreadsheet by their 2013 "Rank" score, then the following are in the top 50:

1. NORWAY
2. SWEDEN
3. FINLAND
4. DENMARK
5. NEW ZEALAND
6. AUSTRIA
7. NETHERLANDS
8. SWITZERLAND
9. LUXEMBOURG
10. AUSTRALIA
11. SINGAPORE
12. CANADA
13. IRELAND
14. GREENLAND
15. JERSEY, CHANNEL ISLANDS
16. UNITED KINGDOM
17. ICELAND
18. GERMANY
19. LIECHTENSTEIN
20. HONG KONG SAR, CHINA
21. UNITED STATES
22. ANDORRA
23. JAPAN
24. BELGIUM
25. ANGUILLA
26. FRANCE
27. CHILE
28. MALTA
29. ARUBA
30. ESTONIA
31. AMERICAN SAMOA
32. BERMUDA
33. GUAM
34. FRENCH GUIANA
35. TAIWAN, CHINA
36. QATAR
37. PORTUGAL
38. CZECH REPUBLIC
39. BARBADOS
40. CYPRUS
41. SPAIN
42. SLOVENIA
43. ISRAEL
44. MONACO
45. SAN MARINO
46. KOREA, REP.
47. MAURITIUS
48. PALAU
49. CAYMAN ISLANDS
50. MARTINIQUE

Countries that are not in the top 50 include

- Greece (78)
- Italy (81)
- India (101)
- China (128)
- Russian Federation (160)

---

### Judicial independence

On the subject of (specifically) judicial independence instead of (more generally) rule of law:

- The UN [Basic Principles on the Independence of the Judiciary](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/ProfessionalInterest/Pages/IndependenceJudiciary.aspx) says that it was,

  > Adopted by the Seventh United Nations Congress on the Prevention of Crime and the Treatment of Offenders held at Milan from 26 August to 
  >   6 September 1985 and endorsed by General Assembly resolutions 40/32 of 29 November 1985 and 40/146 of 13 December 1985

  I think that implies that the General Assembly at least pays lip service to an "independent judiciary".
- There's an [International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Covenant_on_Civil_and_Political_Rights) signed by virtually every country.

  [Article 14 of this](http://www.legislationline.org/documents/action/popup/id/7736) says,

  > All persons shall be equal before the courts and tribunals. In the determination of any criminal charge against him, or of his rights and obligations in a suit at law, everyone shall be entitled to a fair and public hearing by a competent, **independent and impartial tribunal established by law**. The press and the public may be excluded from all or part of a trial for reasons of morals, public order (ordre public) or national security in a democratic society, or when the interest of the private lives of the parties so requires, or to the extent strictly necessary in the opinion of the court in special circumstances where publicity would prejudice the interests of justice; but any judgement rendered in a criminal case or in a suit at law shall be made public except where the interest of juvenile persons otherwise requires or the proceedings concern matrimonial disputes or the guardianship of children.

So the *prima facie* evidence is that virtually all countries have (or claim to have, or agree to have) an independent judiciary.

The World Bank's Governance Indicators referenced above use the [Cingranelli Richards Human Rights Database and Political Terror Scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIRI_Human_Rights_Data_Project) (CIRI) for its measure of judicial independence.

CIRI measures judicial independence on a scale of from 0 to 2.

> - 0= 50+ violations (least respect for human right)
> - 1= 1-49 violations (some respect for human right)
> - 2= 0 violations (full respect for human right)
>
> Data was collected from 1981-2011 for the respective countries and each unit is referred to as a "country-year". A country-year is a single snapshot of space and time for the given country. Other variables, such as the political rights indicators, are scored based on respect for the human right by the same scale, with 0 indicating the least respect and 2 the most respect. The CIRI database uses the annual country reports from the US State Department and Amnesty International as its primary sources.

If I sort that database then the following 65 countries are rated "2":

1. Andorra
2. Antigua and Barbuda
3. Australia
4. Austria
5. Barbados
6. Belgium
7. Belize
8. Bhutan
9. Botswana
10. Canada
11. Cape Verde
12. Chile
13. Croatia
14. Cyprus
15. Czech Republic
16. Denmark
17. Dominica
18. Estonia
19. Finland
20. France
21. Germany
22. Grenada
23. Hungary
24. Iceland
25. Ireland
26. Israel
27. Japan
28. Kiribati
29. Korea, Republic of
30. Lesotho
31. Liechtenstein
32. Lithuania
33. Luxembourg
34. Malawi
35. Malta
36. Marshall Islands
37. Mauritius
38. Micronesia, Federated States of
39. Monaco
40. Namibia
41. Nauru
42. Netherlands
43. New Zealand
44. Norway
45. Palau
46. Papua New Guinea
47. Poland
48. Portugal
49. Saint Kitts and Nevis
50. Saint Lucia
51. Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
52. Samoa
53. San Marino
54. Slovenia
55. Solomon Islands
56. South Africa
57. Spain
58. Suriname
59. Sweden
60. Switzerland
61. Trinidad and Tobago
62. Tuvalu
63. United Kingdom
64. United States of America
65. Vanuatu

I conclude that the "only 40" claimed in the OP is untrue, or uses who-knows-what standard of measurement, or ignores smaller countries from its count, as well as not counting countries like the Bahamas, Greece, Italy, Singapore, and Taiwan, which for whatever reason only scored a "1" (i.e. neither "2" nor "0) on the CIRI report.

Comment: To be fair, there are quite a lot of [microstates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstate), after eliminating them you're left with about forty countries. Not counting microstates is quite common.

Comment: I don't know what the countries with a score of "1" did to deserve that. Saying that they "do not even have an independent judiciary" seems to me it might be an exaggeration.

Comment: Interesting (and sad) that a place where China is nominally in charge comes in ahead of the U.S.

Comment: @TomZych My first thought was that maybe you can afford to [be happy for their success](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmavihara#Exegesis).